# Printing only integer arguments in variable argument function in C

Tags: c

I want to write a C function, which can take any number of arguments and print value of `int` arguments only. I saw `va_list` and `va_arg` in `stdarg.h`, but I couldn't find any mechanism to get the number of arguments. I cannot take first argument as the number of arguments.

Comment: Can you just use the last argument as a flag, like `-1` means the end?

Comment: nope. It seems an impossible task in C.

Comment: You should really explain why do you ask that.

Comment: I think it is possible if you use command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

There's no portable way in standard C to get the number of arguments in variable argument functions.

The common way to solve it is to use the rightmost parameter `parmN` to provide the number of integers explicitly. For instance, your function prototype may look like this:

```
int foo(int number, ...);
```

But this is not an option to you according to your question.

Reference: [**C FAQ**: How can I discover how many arguments a function was actually called with?](http://c-faq.com/varargs/nargs.html)

Comment: I already said that I cannot use first arg as the number of arguments!

Comment: @username_4567 I saw that. Then it's impossible, at least not in a portable way. BTW, `parmN` doesn't have to be the first argument, it's the rightmost argument before `...`

Comment: @username_4567 Why can't you use first argument as a count?

Comment: Yes you do know the number of arguments. When you code a call to your function in C, you are coding a specific call with a specific arity, and you could prepend that arity number to the call.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: unless you are typing blind. ... *of course* you (the programmer) know how many elements are going to come.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sure it's available to the caller of the function. But the function itself has no way knowing the information beforehand.

Comment: @Yu Hao: at *runtime*, arity is *not* available to the caller of the function. It is only known at *compile-time*.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** (portable) **way to get the number of arguments in a variadic function at runtime**. That number is lost at runtime (only the compiler knows it).

Notice that on common processors and [application binary interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI) convention (e.g. [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf) on Linux), the machine itself does not know at runtime the arity of the current call in C; this is also true for others [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). However, when the compiler is compiling a variadic call, it does know the arity at compile time (but does not emit it in the object file).

You could define the convention that your variadic function takes as first argument the number of remaining (variadic) arguments:

```
  void print_integers (int nbints, ...);
```

Then you would implement it e.g.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdarg.h>

 void print_integers (int nbints, ...)
 {
    va_list args;
    va_start (nbints, args);
    for (int ix=0; ix<nbints; ix++) {
      int curarg = va_arg(args, int);
      printf(" %d", curarg);
    };
    va_end(args);
    fflush(NULL);
}
```

If you cannot do this, you have to customize your preprocessor or your compiler. Perhaps a job for your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (*MELT* is a domain specific language to extend GCC). Or perhaps use [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) as your preprocessor.

You could also play some [cpp](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) preprocessor tricks, notably [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) and [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) and [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros). For instance, you might define

```
 void print_integers_str(const char*, ...);
 #define print_my_integers(...) \
    print_integers_str(#__VA_ARGS__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Then `print_my_integers(x,y)` gets expanded to `print_integers_str("x,y", x,y)` and your varadic function `print_integer_str` could parse the `"x,y"` literal string (at least count commas). But with `print_my_integers(f(x,y),g(y)+/*,,*/k)`you may get a nightmare.

To be short: **I recommend give up that goal** and do things otherwise.

Comment: OP has mentioned in his question that he cannot take first argument as the number of arguments.

Comment: True that! A nightmare task in C I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using NARGS macro (in this case limited to 8 args):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define NARGS_SEQ(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,N,...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define fn(...) fn(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

static void (fn)(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i;

    va_start(args, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("%d\n", va_arg(args, int));
    }
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    fn(6, 7, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can loop until -1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define fn(...) fn(0, __VA_ARGS__, -1)

static void (fn)(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int i;

    va_start(args, n);
    while (1) {
        i = va_arg(args, int);
        if (i == -1) break;
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    fn(6, 7, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, you are right, you have to adjust N to MAX_ARGS (as I say in the answer, limited to 8 args)